# Port 443 on iSeries v5r4 is ‘filtered’ to internet clients, even it is allowed in firewall rules. How can I make it ‘open’?

Tags: networking, ibm-midrange

Port was filtered by ISP.

The problem is that HTTPS 443 port isn't accessible from internet, but it is open in our local network.
Our iSeries v5r4 is connected to inet via L2TP withot IPSec.
If no packet filters are active, nmap shows that ports 25, 80, 110 and even 10322 (WAS admin console) have state 'open' on internet IP address.
443 have state 'filtered'.

If I activate the following packet rules:

```
# -----------------------------------------------
# Statements to permit inbound HTTP over STATICIP
# -----------------------------------------------
INCLUDE   FILE = /QIBM/UserData/OS400/TCPIP/PacketRules/Services.i3p
FILTER SET HTTP_INBOUND   ACTION = PERMIT   DIRECTION = OUTBOUND   SRCADDR = *   DSTADDR = *   SERVICE = HTTP_80_FS   JRN = OFF
FILTER SET HTTP_INBOUND   ACTION = PERMIT   DIRECTION = INBOUND   SRCADDR = *   DSTADDR = *   SERVICE = HTTP_80_FC   JRN = OFF
FILTER SET HTTP_INBOUND   ACTION = PERMIT   DIRECTION = OUTBOUND   SRCADDR = *   DSTADDR = *   SERVICE = HTTP_443_FS   JRN = OFF
FILTER SET HTTP_INBOUND   ACTION = PERMIT   DIRECTION = INBOUND   SRCADDR = *   DSTADDR = *   SERVICE = HTTP_443_FC   JRN = OFF
FILTER_INTERFACE   INTERFACE = STATICIP   SET = HTTP_INBOUND
# -----------------------------------------------
```

port 80 is 'open', 443 is 'filtered'.

How can I make it 'open'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ISPs filter specific ports, like RoadRunner used to filter my webserver.  It'd be odd since 80 isn't filtered, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Thanks! You're right.
There is ISP's feature - VPN protection configured by customer. All ports from 0 to 1024 was filtered except 21,22,25,80 and 110.
i5/OS, its ip filter and my packet rules are alright.
Now problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

[IBM's online documentation about IP filtering and NAT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzajb/rzajbrzajb0ippacketsecuritysd.htm) which may help solve the problem.

Comment: Above link to IBM's online documentation cannot be accessed, as it is 'out of service'.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your firewall to open and close TCP/IP ports.

Each firewall has a list of ports (or port ranges) that are open or closed for trafic. PLease consult you firewall/router documentation or consult your system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Port 443 is the SSL port so it is quite possible that either your firewall or your iSeries has a further filter that needs to be set to allow ssl traffic to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!
Firewall is cofigured to open ports 80 and 443. But 443 is filtered anyway.
Our ISP filters no ports.